# Can I suppress Import-SPWeb log created message

Tags: powershell, import

Using the SharePoint Administrator PowerShell command Import-SPWeb, I loop through many backup files, each generates the output:

```
Log file generated:
     C:\somepath\backup.cmp.import.log
```

With the amount of files imported these messages make error and tracking output unmanageable. How can I suppress the message & still generate the log?

The following does not work

```
 Import-SPWeb -Identity... | Out-File $null
```

Update:

I have attempted to use Start-Job with a script block but it does not seem to actually run the command.

Invoke command with scriptblock outputs the writing I want to avoid

I have been attempting to work with runspace but even InvokeAsync seems to output the writing I wish to avoid

Comment: did you try with -ErrorAction? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/11/03/erroraction-and-errorvariable.aspx

Comment: If you execute Import-SPWeb you will see it is not an error or a warning (both preferences are "SilentlyContinue") also this occurs without using Verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew for a while that answer would reside in calling Import-SPWeb  from a different console context since the SharePoint command seems to call `console.writeline ("str");`
I have learned a lot about creating powershell runspaces & Invoke commands. Ultimately I found that a solution in spawning new powershell process which cleans itself up.

Step 1: create a script for the action

```
  [CmdletBinding ()]
 Param ([string]$url, [string]$backupfile)
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.powershell -EA 0
  Import-SPWeb $url -Path $backupfile
  # other commands and error handling you may want
```

Step 2: run script in 2nd powershell process

```
 Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ".\myscript.ps1 -url http://site -backupfile c:\backup.cmp" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

This will now execute Import-SPWeb, generate the import.log, and not output ugly text to screen. Also you may wish to look into additional start-process parameters like -RedirectStandardOutput

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do this in powershell (hide output), I usually test these three ways, but I cannot try it right now :

1. `[void]Import-SPWeb ...` at the beginning of the line could work
2. `Import-SPWeb ... > $null` at the end of the line
3. `Import-SPWeb ... | Out-Null`

Please give feedback about results.

Comment: '[void] import-spweb' is error. '[void](import-spweb)' still outputs. '| out-null' still outputs. '> $null' still outputs

Comment: can you try with `*>$null` at the end ? (If you're using PSv3). And also `$null = Import-SPWeb ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use the -NoLogFile parameter.

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://site -Path //server/share/file.cmp -NoLogFile
```

Comment: I'm attempting to have my cake and eat it too. I need logs generated as a requirement but I want to know how to supress the text for a smooth user experience  ( & to justify time spent ). Still, thanks for contributing!

Comment: You can't. The code has a Console.WriteLine if you don't use -NoLogFile it will always show the message.